# socket.io-client@0.9.7 with typescript and webpack2 import error

Tags: typescript, socket.io, webpack-2

```
ERROR in ./~/socket.io-client/bin/builder.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\work\brickman2\node_modules\socket.io-client\bin'
@ ./~/socket.io-client/bin/builder.js 11:9-22
@ ./~/socket.io-client/lib/io.js
@ ./src/services/pusher.ts
@ multi main

ERROR in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\work\brickman2\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib'
@ ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 16:9-22
@ ./~/socket.io-client/lib/util.js
@ ./~/socket.io-client/lib/io.js
@ ./src/services/pusher.ts
@ multi main

ERROR in ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'E:\work\brickman2\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib'
@ ./~/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 15:12-36
@ ./~/socket.io-client/lib/util.js
@ ./~/socket.io-client/lib/io.js
@ ./src/services/pusher.ts
@ multi main
```

I'm searched with google and github issus, but no one work for me.

socket.io-client@0.9.7 is a old version, But can not to update it. because the socket.io version in server is 0.9.7 and can not change. if I update the client will not connet the server.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and have found the next solution-replacing requiring socket-io.client for bundled version of it.

ES5 version

```
//var io = require('socket.io-client');
var io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'); //worked solution
```

ES6 version

```
//import io from 'socket.io-client';
import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'; //worked solution
```

Comment: Life saver! Works as advertised